# Delete certain rows if complete row contains zeros with dt

Tags: datatable

I am asking myself the following question.

Is there a smart way to solve the problem using the package data.table instead of solving it with data.frames. I got a huge dataset and want to adress this problem as efficient as possible

```
Random <- sample(c("A","B","C","D","E","F","G"), size = 100, replace = 
TRUE)
Year <- sample(c(2000,2001,2002,2003,2004,2005), 100, TRUE)
Value <- sample(c(1,2,3,4), 100, TRUE)

data <- data.frame(Random,Year,Value)

# open dplyr library
library(dplyr)

#Group data by Random and year and count Values that are not NA 
data %>% group_by(Random, Year) %>% summarise(count =    
length(Value[!is.na(Value)]))
```

I still wish to delete all the rows that do not change. So to be precise, all the rows which have the same min and max :)

EDITED following @Hannie ´s comment.

Comment: Hello! Could you maybe include the `dput(your_data)` in your question? That makes it easier for others to work on the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Say you want to remove all rows where columns `b`, `c`, and `d` are equal. You can use `Reduce` and `==`.

```
set.seed(0)
dt <- data.frame(a = sample(letters[1:3], 100, T)
                 , b = sample(1:2, 100, T)
                 , c = sample(1:2, 100, T)
                 , d = sample(1:2, 100, T))



df[!Reduce(`==`, df[, -1]),]
```

In this example though, it's probably better to remove those rows before using `xtabs`.

```
data <- data.frame(Random,Year,Value)
library(data.table)
setDT(data)

data[, .(Count = sum(!is.na(Value))), by = .(Random, Year)
     ][, if(!Reduce(`==`, Count)) .SD, by = Random]
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, it would also be the same if your variance does not equal 0. You can do that using apply and var together, and then index on your dataframe.

I named the dataframe `x`

```
x[apply(x, 1, var)!=0,]
```

The `1` means you're calculating the variance over rows. Output:

```
  2000 2001 2002 2003 2004
b    1    2    3    4    5
d    6    7    8    9    5
f    1    2    3    4    5
```

I couldn't get your code to work so I created a data.frame like this:

```
dput(x)
structure(list(`2000` = c(0, 1, 2, 6, 1, 1), `2001` = c(0, 2, 
2, 7, 1, 2), `2002` = c(0, 3, 2, 8, 1, 3), `2003` = c(0, 4, 2, 
9, 1, 4), `2004` = c(0, 5, 2, 5, 1, 5)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("a", 
"b", "c", "d", "e", "f"))
```

Which has this output:

```
  2000 2001 2002 2003 2004
a    0    0    0    0    0
b    1    2    3    4    5
c    2    2    2    2    2
d    6    7    8    9    5
e    1    1    1    1    1
f    1    2    3    4    5
```